# How can I include carriage return within content using opentips.js?

Tags: javascript

I'm using opentips.js and trying to include a carriage return in the content. I tried using ascii and \n but both don't work. I feel like there should be an easy answer for this.

```
<body>
   <div id="trigger">This is the trigger.</div>
</body>

<script>
   var myInput = $("#trigger");
   var text1 = "here is some text";
   var text2 = "this should be on the next line";
   var content = text1 + String.fromCharCode(13) + text2;
   new Opentip(myInput, content, {});
</script>
```

Comment: `\n` is the js version, but if it's html output, then use `<br>`

Comment: Thank yuo  "<br>" worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid using additional markup (e.g. `<br>`), `\n` should work if you adjust the white-space. But then that may have other unwanted side effects.

```js
$("#trigger").html("First line of text\nSecond line of text");
```

```css
#trigger {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trigger"></div>
```